How to include local dependencies in Node.js Google Cloud Run service
I am trying to turn a function in my project repo into a Cloud Run service. In my file, I include some local dependencies using require statements. I followed the quickstart instructions on Google Run, and in my package.json I included these dependencies using the file indicator. I've included the dependencies portion of my package.json below:
  "dependencies": {
    "express": "^4.17.1",
    "embeddings": "file:../../embeddings.js",
    "opt": "file:../../opt.js",
    "gpt": "file:../../gpt.js",
    "pinecone": "file:../../pinecone.js",
    "users": "file:../../users.js"
  }

When I try to deploy the service with gcloud run deploy, I run into a 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND' error. I can't find any info online about how to properly configure this.

I'm not a Node.js developer but familiar with Cloud Run.
I suspect your issue is that gcloud run deploy attempts to build a container for your project (using a buildpack) but is unable to access references outside the context (of your current project; in the current folder).
You've choices:

Containerize the app yourself
Private registry
Vendor
Manually configure node_modules to include the dependencies

Vendor
Example:
.
├── a
│   ├── index.js
│   └── package.json
└── b
    ├── index.js
    └── package.json

Where b has a dependency on a and b's package.json includes:
{
  "name": "b",
  "dependencies": {
    "a": "file:../a"
  }
}


NOTE The package is outside (..) of the context.

This will fail.
To vendor a, move it under a(ny) designated folder in b:
.
├── index.js
├── package.json
└── vendor
    └── a
        ├── index.js
        └── package.json

Where b retains its dependency on a and b's package.json includes:
{
  "name": "b",
  "dependencies": {
    "a": "file:vendor/a"
  }
}


NOTE The package is within the context and found by the buildpack.

This will succeed.

NOTE I'm using jobs for convenience but the principal applies.

gcloud run jobs deploy b \
--source=${PWD} \
--project=${PROJECT} \
--region=${REGION}

Job [b] has successfully been deployed.

...and I'm able to run the Job successfully.
